# How to read button data?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pysimplegui

In an attempt to call commands by the module subprocess, I made this program to check the conditions of my network. When I enter this value in the fields, nothing of the variable returns. How do I read a button's data and send it to a subpr string?

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess


def subpr(cmd , url) :
    result = subprocess.run( [f'{cmd}, {url}'] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
    print( result.stdout.decode( 'utf-8' ) )


class prog :
    def __init__(self) :
        # Layout
        layout = [
            [sg.T( 'Output in data' )] ,
            [sg.Output( size=(100 , 10) , key='in' )] ,
            [sg.Text( '1:' ) , sg.Input( key='exit1' )] ,
            [sg.Text( '2:' ) , sg.Input( key='exti2' )] ,
            [sg.Button( 'Env' ) , sg.Button('Clear'),sg.Exit( 'Exit' )]
        ]

        self.layout = sg.Window( 'Software TEST' ).layout( layout )

        self.event , self.values = self.layout.read( )

    def inic(self) :
        a = self.values['exit1']
        b = self.values['exit2']

        while True :
            if self.event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or self.event == 'Exit' :
                break

            if self.event == 'Clear' :
                self.layout['in'].update( '' )

            if self.event == "Env" :
                subpr( a , b)


progm = prog()
prog.inic()
```